# How to add ipv6 static route?

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I'm new to IPv6, this is my home network

```
                                   +------------------------------------------+                                   
                                   |                                          |                                   
                                   |                  Router                  |                                   
                                   |                                          |                                   
                                   |                                          |                                   
                                   |                                          |                                   
                                   |                                          |                                   
                                   |             fe80::fe7c:2ff:fed5:a236     |                                   
                                   +------------------------------------------+                                   
                                                         |                                                        
                                                         |                                                        
                                                         |                                                        
                                                         |                                                        
                                                         |                                                        
                      +----------------------------------|-----------------------------------+                    
                      |                                                                      |                    
                      |                                                                      |                    
                      |                                                                      |                    
                      |                                                                      |                    
                      |                                                                      |                    
+------------------------------------------+                          +------------------------------------------+
|                   wlan0                  |                          |                    eth0                  |
|         fe80::8e70:5aff:fe62:7180/64     |                          |          fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052/64    |
|                                          |                          |                                          |
|                                          |                          |                                          |
|                  Laptop                  |                          |                  VPN Gateway             |
|                                          |                          |                                          |
|                                          |                          |                                          |
+------------------------------------------+                          +------------------------------------------+
```

My ISP doesn't give me IPv6 address, but I run VPN software on VPN Gateway, I've created these iptables rules on VPN Gateway:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg_vpn  -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg_vpn -j ACCEPT

ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg_vpn  -j MASQUERADE
ip6tables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg_vpn -j ACCEPT
```

I know how to add ipv4 rule on my laptop, `ip route add default via vpn_gateway_ip dev wlan0`, but it seems this doesn't work on ipv6? So how can I write the ipv6 rule?

I've already run `ip -6 route add default via fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052 dev wlan0`, but `ping -6 www.google.com` will return `From _gateway (fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052%wlan0) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address` .

`ping fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052` also has no response, but `ping -I wlan0 fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052` will return correct response.

I don't want the IPv6 address from ISP, I want all my network traffic go through VPN.

Comment: All your addresses are link-local addresses. Do you really want to use these? Why not use Unique Local Addresses (ULA)?

Comment: "I don't want the IPv6 address from ISP" – nobody said you need to use those. The VPN server _is_ your new ISP in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The switch you are looking for is `-6`:

```
mtak@gen1:~$ sudo ip -6 route add default via 2001:470:xxxx::1
mtak@gen1:~$ ip -6 route list
2001:470:xxxx::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via 2001:470:xxxx::1 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

---

Why are you messing around with NAT for IPv6? The whole point of IPv6 is that NAT is not required anymore. If you have IPv6 available on your VPN gateway, just route it plain an simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as in IPv4:

```
ip route add default via fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052 dev wlan0
```

You might want to be more specific about it being an IPv6 route – either use `ip -6`, or specify `::/0` instead of "default". (That is, `ip r add ::/0 via` or `ip -6 r add default via`).

However, what *is* different from IPv4 is that your only LAN addresses right now are *link-local.* They're not merely "private" – the `fe80::/64` prefix is strictly scoped to the same link, and packets sent from such IP addresses are not to be forwarded by routers *even if* there's a NAT/masquerade rule present.

(Link-local addresses can, however, be used as the 'gateway' for routes because a gateway address has to be from the same link *anyway* – in both IPv6 and IPv4 equally. So `via fe80...` is fine.)

If you want your LAN to have IPv6 access through the VPN, you'll need to assign your devices global-scope addresses (in addition to the link-local ones). Preferably, this would be a "public" /64 range routed through your VPN server, in which case you wouldn't need any form of NAT in ip6tables – your devices would just directly use their global addresses.

But if you really don't have a public /64 to spare (or if you're using a commercial VPN service which expects a single device only), then the **`fd00::/8`** "Unique local address" range is your other option. That's the direct IPv6 equivalent to IPv4's RFC1918 private addresses – you're supposed to pick a random /48 from it (like `fd84:1b4e:6281::/48` for example), from which you then assign /64's to your subnets (like `fd84:1b4e:6281:0::/64` for the local LAN). These addresses *are* forwardable (in the same way as 192.168.x), so ip6tables NAT will work like you'd expect.

You can assign IPv6 addresses either manually (using `ip addr add ... dev wlan0`) or announce the prefix automatically (using `radvd` running on the VPN gateway, which will also announce the `::/0` default route at the same time).

Comment: I've already run `ip -6 route add default via fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052 dev wlan0`, but `ping -6 www.google.com` will return `From _gateway (fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052%wlan0) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Beyond scope of source address`. `ping fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052` also has no response, but `ping -I wlan0 fe80::3686:d00c:4a2b:1052` will return correct response.

Comment: The rest of my post (starting with 3rd paragraph) answers this. The way you add the route is not the problem. It's the _source address_ that is the problem.